# Computing this definite double integral

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, normal-distribution

Given two mean zero normally distributed independent random variables $x \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2), y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,k\sigma^2)$, I want to find $\mathbb{E}[xy|x + y > 0]$. I have got to the point of the following double integral but I can't see how I can proceed further. I am not even sure if the expression is correct.
$$\mathbb{E}[xy|x + y > 0] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \int_{-\infty}^\infty  xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx\int_{-x}^\infty \frac{y}{\sqrt{2\pi k}\sigma}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2k\sigma^2}}dy$$

I think final expression might be in the form of 'erf' or $\Phi$ but I don't know how. I shall be glad if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: It seem that you assume independence, do you?

Comment: Yes I have added that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $z=\frac{y^2}{2k\sigma^2}$.

Comment: It was also questioned that the integral given was valid!

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. When I make that substitution the expression evaluates to zero. Does that mean that the expectation is zero or have I made any error?